# How can a France-Philippines couple visit each other?

Tags: france, covid-19, philippines

My girlfriend lives in Philippines, I am from France.

Right now, because of covid19, I can't find a way for me to go there or a way for her to come to me.

I even tried to see if Spain was a possibility.

Is there somewhere we both can go?

Comment: My wife has tried to go home to the Philippines (from the UK) but has dismissed it for the moment as just too hard.  Despite the historical connection, I would not expect any advantage to going via Spain.  You might have more chance via the US but that is the long way round.

Comment: Where in the Philippines?  Even if you get to Manila, it still might be complicated to get to  other parts of the country.

Comment: @badjohn in Dipolog City

Comment: @DJClayworth indeed, but she like I call her like that. I will edit my question.

Comment: As you probably know, Dipolog is far from Manila so even if you figure out how to get to Manila, you should check how to travel within the Philippines.  I am not up to date but there have been strict internal restrictions and, at the moment, things might change fast.

Comment: @badjohn indeed, I did search on how to go from Manila to Dipolog when there is no pandemic restrictions. We will have to wait then :(

Comment: She could be a "fiancée" instead of a girlfriend, if you are engaged to be married.  This might make a difference under some visa schemes, though I don't know if it makes a difference for either France or the Philippines.

Comment: Is the difficulty ‘just’ Covid, or is it visa-related too? https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php

Comment: Both of our countries have set access restrictions for the other country, neither green or red, each are considered as orange, and only certain kind of persons can do the travel. It would be fine if we were married.

Comment: Have you considered meeting in another country, one that both of you could currently enter as tourists?

Comment: I did consider it, I tried to check Thailand and Spain. But in fact I think she can’t leave the country.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.